# Input an if then command into a vba macros that will loop through a column

Tags: vba, excel

I Am trying to make a macros that will look at the hour value of cells in a certain row, sort them based on my if, then, else criteria and produce a result based on this that will loop my column.

So if the hour is <= 15 And >= 11, then result is "Lunch".

I am very new to VBA, but here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Time_Sorter()

Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 1 To Rows.count            
    If Hour("J" & i) <= 15 And Hour("J" & i) >= 11 Then
        result = "Lunch"    
    ElseIf Hour("J" & i) <= 16 And Hour("J" & i) >= 17 Then
        result = "Pre-Dinner"    
    ElseIf Hour("J" & i) <= 18 And Hour("J" & i) >= 21 Then
        result = "Dinner"    
    ElseIf Hour("J" & i) <= 22 And Hour("J" & i) >= 23 Then
        result = "Late Night"
    Else
        result = "Other"    
    End If       
Next i

End Sub
```

I keep getting the message

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

And I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any insight would be very appreciated!

Comment: what is the format of the cells in Column "J" ? is it of Date & Time ? can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Hi, the column j is in the format is Time, with the format of a 24 hour clock so the data 2012-07-30  12:13:00 PM displays in the cell as 12:13:00

Comment: so try my code below and see if t works as you intend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after something like the code below.

Iv'e replaced your multiple `ElseIf`s with a constructed `Select Case`.

**Code**

```
Sub Time_Sorter()

Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

' loop from the first row until last row with data in column ""j"
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case Hour(Range("J" & i).Value)
        Case 11 To 15
            result = "Lunch"
        Case 16 To 17
            result = "Pre-Dinner"
        Case 18 To 21
            result = "Dinner"
        Case 22 To 23
            result = "Late Night"
        Case Else
            result = "Other"
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you! So in case like this would Select case be a simpler/easier option to use?

Comment: @JennyMaily for your current task it is, you can add more scenarios to the `Select Case` easily